# Travel after removal from UK

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, canadian-citizens, removal

I'm a Canadian citizen currently living in Iraq. I recently went to the U.K. for work and they denied me entry and removed me. My question is, if I go back to Canada, will I be questioned about it? I also want to know if I can visit the U.S.A.?

Comment: Canada might question you about it.  They can't deny entry to Canada, though.  Being denied entry to the UK does not in and of itself make you inadmissible to the US, but the US might also take exception to whatever fact it was that caused the UK to deny entry, and therefore also deny entry independently.

Comment: Why were you refused entry to the UK? You received paperwork when you were refused; please upload an image of it (with personal information blacked out). Without knowing the particulars of why you were refused, only sheer speculation is possible.

Comment: I will explain in brief, I went back to iraq for work and marriage, and I changed my mind, I fought with my father and I decided to leave to scotland because my cousin was there.  When I reached airport at Edinburgh they asked me why I didn't have return ticket. I told them that I was here for work and that I wanted to apply for work visa here. they start asking me questions and they detained me for almost 18 hours and removed me back.